# Direct Access to Web Element in Firefox (like .Object if IE) in HP QTP

Tags: firefox, qtp, automated-tests

is there any way to get access to DOM object when running script in QTP in Firefox?

When running in IE, I could use

```
Browser().Page().WebButton.Object
```

How could I do something similar in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with QTP 11 there is `.Object` support with Firefox too.

If you're using an older version you will have to resort to running some JavaScript on the page which is exposed as `Frame.RunScript` starting in QTP 11 (oh the irony).